# Getting distinct users in a messages database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For a `messages` table with the following structure

```
id, sender_id, receiver_id, text
```

I want to build a  list of distinct users (ordered by message id) who have either sent a message to or received one from the current session holder. The list should contain a user only once.

A query such as:

```
"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender_id = '$sess_id' OR receiver_id = '$sess_id'";
```

yields duplicates i.e. multiple rows with the same user. Does one necessarily have to do the filtering after the SQL query or is there an SQL query that will yield the desired unique list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
SELECT sender_id
FROM   messages
WHERE  receiver_id = '$sess_id'
UNION
SELECT receiver_id
FROM   messages
WHERE  sender_id = '$sess_id'
```

Comment: Alternatively `SELECT DISTINCT sender_id, receiver_id FROM messages HAVING sender_id = '$sess_id' OR receiver_id = '$sess_id';`

Comment: should the "HAVING" be a "WHERE" instead?...The second doesn't seem to meet my requirements cleanly. The first certainly does though...Thanks!

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: It doesn't order the resulting set by message id, but other than that this answer indeed provides a very clean solution.

Comment: i believe he deleted the second option i was referring to. This option certainly provides a clean solution as you have said...and its simple enough to add the ORDER BY...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  CASE receiver_id WHEN '$sess_id' THEN sender_id ELSE receiver_id END AS user_id
FROM messages
WHERE receiver_id = '$sess_id'
   OR sender_id = '$sess_id'
GROUP BY CASE receiver_id WHEN '$sess_id' THEN sender_id ELSE receiver_id END
ORDER BY MAX(message_id)
```

MySQL allows you to reference column aliases in the GROUP BY clause, so you could also simply do:

```
…
GROUP BY user_id
…
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the distinct keyword:

```
SELECT distinct sender_id
FROM   messages
WHERE  receiver_id = '$sess_id'
UNION
SELECT distinct receiver_id
FROM   messages
WHERE  sender_id = '$sess_id'
```

More information can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html